# How to dequeue bootstrap for footer in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, tailwind-css, bootstrap-5

I want to add custom code(containing tailwind classes) for the footer in my WordPress website. But the browser applies css of these classes as per the bootstrap stylesheet. So, I want to exclude/dequeue Bootstrap for my footer only.

Comment: So you are using bootstrap 4, bootstrap 5, and tailwind all on the same project?  I would advise picking just one of those because the overhead and overlap from all of those will be massively confusing

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your question doesn't include enough information.

Comment: Yes, using multiple layout libraries (even several different versions of one library) is an all-around bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no available method to exclude or dequeue your style specifically for the footer, as the page layout is printed as a whole during a page request.

I recommend clearing bootstrap class names from the footer section while applying your tailwind styles alone.